# How to keep leading zeros when subtracting 2 numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

This:

```
$difference = 05-1;
```

results in

```
4
```

same if I do this:

```
$difference = 05-01;
```

is there a inbuilt way to subtract while keeping leading zeros? I know I can check to see if the difference has only 1 character or not and if so add a leading zero but was just wondering if there is a default way to get the result back with 0 already in it.

Comment: Careful with this. Leading zeroes indicate octal notation, so unexpected things like this may happen: `echo 012 - 4; // prints 6`.

Comment: Watch out! Leading zeroes indicates an octal number, so `08-04` will result in an error. And `023-005` is not 018.

Comment: In this script I will always be subtracting 2 numbers, the 1st may or may not have a leading zero (it will only have a leading zero if it's between 1 and 9) and the second number will always be the number 1 (without leading zero). Can this scenario cause any unexpected results?

Comment: Yes, if the first number is `08` or `09`. Those aren't valid octal numbers, so it just assumes zero. `echo 08-1;` prints '-1'.

Comment: @Wiseguy ahh alright, thanks for the heads up. I will convert the 1st number to be without zero and then add the leading zero to the answer only, will save me a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I dont think PHP will natively keep the leading 0's unless its a float. In PHPs mind `4` is `4` not `04` tho `0.4` is `0.4`

So if you need the leading `0` in ints lower the `10` pad it with [str_pad():](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
<?php 
$difference = (05-1);

echo str_pad($difference, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);//04
?>

<?php 
$difference = 234;

echo str_pad($difference, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);//234
?>
```

Comment: That pads the result to a predefined length. The OP asked for a way to "keep" leading zeroes, which makes me think that `05-1` should be printed as `04` but `5-1` should be printed as `4` (and `00005-1` as `00004`). The OP also needs to clarify whether they want to keep all the zeroes, or keep the same number of places (i.e., would `010-9` be `001` or `01`?).

Comment: @octern The method in this answer works fine for my situation, I am only subtracting whole numbers and all single digits should have a leading 0.

Comment: @JakeRow123 yes i understood that was the question (cosmetic output), tho it seemed to confuse others abit.

Comment: It could also be padded with [printf format](http://php.net/sprintf): `$diff = sprintf('%02d', 05 - 1);`

Comment: I wasn't able to infer all that, but if the number always has no more than 1 leading zero, and is always single digit, and the result is never larger than the original number, then yes, this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a matter of outputting you can use printf() to add leading zeroes. The following:

```
<?php
printf("Result: %02d", 04-1);
?>
```

will output:

```
Result: 03
```

the **%02d** translates to fill with '0' (**%0** 2d) for 2 spaces (%0 **2** d) and format as an integer (%02 **d**). A lot can be done with printf() to set precision, add leading characters, and use placeholders while outputting text.